# How to configure backend user/group in Typo3?

Tags: typo3, backend, usergroups

I created a group with full rights in access list and added every single page in DB Mounts. Next I created a user and added him to the group (the user has full access rights and all pages added in DB Mounts). But when I log in as my new backend user, I don't see any page in pagetree. Why? And how to fix it?

ANSWER: 
I wasn't set a group in Access in Web tab

Comment: Did you set the proper rights to the pages in the "access"-module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the access module. 
You have 3 kind of permission to set there. Fact that you've set DB mount for page doesn't mean anything. It is not for that

To see a page the page needs to have set proper access (it is like chmod). Allow this ussergroup to have access to pages and the user will see it

DB mounts is used for access to records like news in diffrent pid`s